# Simplify a css expression

Tags: css

Is it possible to simplify the following CSS expression?

```
.table-width-1 {
  width:1%;
}

.table-width-2 {
  width:2%;
}

.table-width-3 {
  width:3%;
}

.table-width-4 {
  width:4%;
}

.table-width-5 {
  width:5%;
}
```

and so on, until 100%.

Thanks.

Comment: Not possible with CSS. Definately possible with Sass/SCSS or LESS

Comment: What is the problem? If it is too long, just omit some elements, if you don't need them. If you are too lazy to write it, you can have style.php file and generate it on server in a for loop.

Comment: [If you are convenient using jquery, check the head in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ssCE/)

Comment: And another +1 for @Bhavik! I had no idea that you could modify $('head') with js. Ya lern sumpin' ever day... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't simplify that with CSS alone. But you could use some PHP code to calculate the width for every class like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
            echo '.table-width-'. $i .' { width: '. $table-width .'%; }';
        }
    ?>
</style>
```

Put that into your `<head></head>`. This generates your 100 CSS classes with names `.table-width-1` to `-100` and `width: 1%` to `100%`. Makes it super easy to add/change attributes to/in every single class, too. That's how I would do it.